# Why is my BezierCurve shaded like a tube?

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves, geometry, bevel

I've added a BezierCurve, and beveled it with a square curve.  The ends are square as expected, but the shading makes it look like a pipe (beveled with a circle).  I would expect a shading more like the cube I've added for comparison.
[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the edge split modifier, as shown here:
[image]

Alternatively,convert to a mesh, then check the "auto smooth" box in the object data properties panel.
This should preserve the sharp edges in shading

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!

Comment: Great answer :) Just a tip ... Would be even more awesome if your screens proportion (scale) fits to web page width. Like now the first is too small to read properties editor and second one is oversized and has to be scroll to see end.

Comment: @vklidu: The questionable blessings of having a 4k and an HD monitor...

Comment: I'm working on 5K ... that is not the point :)

Answer (score 3):

Because by default is spline set under
*Properties Editor > Data Properties > Active Spline* as **Smooth**

When *Smooth* unchecked, curve become shaded *Flat*, which means flat also in curvature.

[image]

To make it smoother you can increase **Resolution U** (segment subdivisions)

[image]

But in some cases it would be still segmented ... so *Edge Split*  modifier seems to be better choise anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, for a square profile, you don't need a profile object; this 3D curve has been given a native bevel at minimum resolution, all vertices tilted to 45 degrees...

[image]

And a curve can be given a *Bevel* Modifier to stand in the way of smooth shading interpolation over sharp corners: here, 2 segments with a profile shape of 1.

And the bevel is adjustable, if you do use a profile object:

[image]